# HTML DOM Validator - PHP or JavaScript

Tags: html, dom, parsing

I am posting a form with a textarea in it.

I allow HTML to be posted.

Now I wish to check if the user has closed the tags he has put in the html he posted... when I am displaying that HTML, the broken tags like divs and tables etc spoil the whole page display... any way to check for proper tag useage in php or javascript ?

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at a PHP tool called [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) -- there is a [demo page](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php) available, if you want to quickly check what it can do.

It takes "sort of" HTML as input, and gives well-formed HTML as ouput ; this way, you are not forcing your users to input well-formed HTML, but you can "correct" what they typed.

Another nice thing is, you can specify which tags and attributes are allowed ; which is good for security too :

- for instance, you can allow `<p>` and `<strong>` tags, but not `<script>`.
- you can also allow `<a>` + `href` ; but not `<a>` + `onclick`

For instance, here is some not-well-formed HTML you can give to it :

```
<p>this is a <strong>test</p>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('glop');</script>
<p>And this is another <em>te<strong>st</em></strong></p>
```

And here is the well-formed / secured HTML given as output :

```
<p>this is a <strong>test</strong></p>
<p>And this is another <em>te<strong>st</strong></em></p>
```

What has changed ?

- the `<strong>` tag in the first paragraph has been automatically closed
- the `<script>` tag and its content have been removed
- the order of the closing `<em>` and `<strong>` tags in the second paragraph has been corrected.

This was just a quick example, of course -- I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. If you're looking for a rich text editor, try one of the more mature solutions available instead of trying to reinventing the wheel/

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

You'll need regular expressions to check for closed tags. It's a little complicated for someone unfamiliar with regex.

Use this search as a starting point:
http://www.google.com.kw/search?q=regex+html+tags